# Hosting a .net application in Apache server in Linux

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, asp.net-core, apache2

Am trying to Host my ASP.net application in Apache server on my linux (ubuntu) . 
I have configured and published my ASP.net application.

Its hard to host the application in linux does any one guide me to host my application ?

Without Mono-Project is there any solution to do so?

Comment: Microsoft has a really nice guide on this.  It is using CentOs so the commands are different for Ubuntu but that shouldn't be too complicated to follow.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/apache-proxy

Comment: To add on to what @Woot linked to, this covers Linux hosting in general (but not Apache specifically): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction